# yahoo api search.termextract always return empty result

Tags: api, yahoo-api

I get empty results for any request I do to the API service to obtain related terms (table search.termextract).

For example the query:

**select * from search.termextract where context = 'Install system an example with internet word other'**

I tested using console http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/ and direct request as follow:

http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?format=json&q=select%20*%20from%20search.termextract%20where%20context='Install+system+an+example+with+internet+word+other'

(Sorry: The link should be copy/paste in address bar)

But I always get empty result.

What I'm missing? Maybe there is some limitation? Maybe the content should fulfil some requirement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For archive purpose, even I get empty result (and not a notification/error), the search.termextract seems to be deprecated now, and should be used http://developer.yahoo.com/contentanalysis/

For example:

**select * from contentanalysis.analyze where text="Install system an example with internet word other"**